# Compile error ibex

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

I have been working on this project on some time now, and am stuck. I am trying to transform an XML with an XSL stylesheet via ibex PDF creator to generate a PDF file. It seems that I dont get around this this error: 
"server:xml Exception there is a invalid data at root level on line 1 position 39"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    xmlns:main="http://rep.oio.dk/ubl/xml/schemas/0p71/maindoc/"
    xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns="http://rep.oio.dk/ubl/xml/schemas/0p71/pie/"
    xmlns:com="http://rep.oio.dk/ubl/xml/schemas/0p71/common/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<xsl:strip-space elements='*'/>

   <xsl:template match="Invoice">

         <fo:root>

        <fo:layout-master-set>

            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="page" margin='2.5cm'>
              <fo:region-body region-name="body" />
            </fo:simple-page-master>

        </fo:layout-master-set>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="Invoice"/>

         </fo:root>

</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="Invoice">
            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="page">

                <fo:flow flow-name="body">


                <fo:block font='bold 14pt helvetica'>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
                </fo:block>

             <xsl:apply-templates select="com:Note"/>

                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="com:Note">

    <fo:block font='bold 12pt helvetica'>
                <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
    </fo:block>

     <xsl:apply-templates select="para"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="para">

    <fo:block font='10pt helvetica'>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your XSLT sample is missing `<` before the opening `xsl:stylesheet` on this first line. Is this just a typo with your question?

Comment: Line 1 Position 39 as I checked in notepad++ is right after the prolog, so this might be the actual error... anyway lets wait for OP to confirm

Comment: Actually, the < before the opening xsl:stylesheet is in my code. But when copypaiste it in here, I somehow manage to remove the <.

Comment: Can you also show the XML you are trying to transform? Thank you!

Comment: I cant show all but here is the main part :

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--111111111111-->
<Invoice xmlns:main="http://rep.oio.dk/ubl/xml/schemas/0p71/maindoc/" xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns="http://rep.oio.dk/ubl/xml/schemas/0p71/pie/" xmlns:com="http://rep.oio.dk/ubl/xml/schemas/0p71/common/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<com:ID>90000001</com:ID>
<com:IssueDate>2016-03-09</com:IssueDate>
<com:TypeCode>PIE</com:TypeCode>
<main:InvoiceCurrencyCode>NOK</main:InvoiceCurrencyCode>
<com:Note>Test Invoice
</com:Note>

Comment: You may want to [edit] this into your question, it is kind of important. And **make sure that your error also happens with the shortened XML fragment**.

Comment: Looking at your question, it seems you did not.

Comment: You edited this in my code Rad, do I need to write this in the question?

Comment: Anyone who have a clue what can be wrong here? Anyone with experience with Ibex PDF Creator maybe?